Geometric proof: congruency of two triangles
A few months ago I asked a question regarding an analytical geometry problem.
One of the possible solution involves proving the congruency of two triangles: if the triangles are congruent, their heights must be equal,  therefore a pair of vertices is symmetrical.
The problem:
Knowing that A$(0,0)$ and B $(4,0)$, the problem asked to find a locus of orthocentres H of $\triangle APB$ as P varied. P $\in \gamma: x^2+y^2-4x+4y=0$
My solution:
One possible (and elegant) solution is the following: i drew the perpendicular lines and created a new point H' $\in (\gamma \hspace{0,2cm} \cap$ f). (Is it written in the correct way?)
If you show that H and H' are symmetrical about the x axis, you get the solution for free since you know that the locus of H' is $\gamma$ and therefore the locus of H will be the circumference symmetrical about the x axis, namely $\gamma': x^2+y^2-4x-4y$.

Where I am stuck:
You need to show that $\triangle AHB \cong \triangle AH'B$.
I was able to prove with the properties of circles, that $\angle APB = 45°$ and that $\angle AHB= \angle AH'B= 135°$. However, I am now stuck and I can't show any other congruency of sides/angles. Can you help me? Thank you.

That $AHB, AH'B$ are congruent is a well-known result. It is often stated as "The reflection of the orthocenter about any side, lies on the circumcircle".

Let $D$, $E$, and $F$ be the foot of the altitudes from $A$, $B$, and $P$, respectively. Note that
$$\angle HAB=90-\angle B=\angle H'PB=\angle H'AB.$$
The first equality comes from looking at right triangle $\triangle ADB$, the second one comes from looking at right triangle $\triangle PFB$, and the last equality comes from the fact that $\angle H'PB$ and $\angle H'AB$ see the same arc $H'B$. Similarly,
$$\angle HBA=90-\angle A=\angle H'PA=H'BA,$$
and since $\triangle HAB$ and $\triangle H'AB$ share a side, they are therefore congruent by SAS congruence.

Thank you for this solution! With $\angle B$ you mean $\angle ABP$ and with $\angle A$ you mean $\angle EAB$ right?

@Lorenzo Yep, that's right. I usually use one letter angles to directly refer to the angle of a given triangle.
